# vuex - cannot dispatch action from another module

Tags: javascript, vuex

I split my vuex store to different modules. when i try to dispatch actionA that is defined in module A from a module B's action I get the following error in console:

*actionA undefined*

I assume this means i did not configure or imported something correctly, but for the life of me i can't figure out what exactly. some pseudo code for reference:

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import moduleA from './modules/moduleA';
import moduleB from './modules/moduleB';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    modules: { 
        moduleA,
        moduleB
    },
    state: { ...
    },
    getters: { ...
    },
    mutations: { ...
    },
```

moduleA.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
namespaced: true,
    state: { 
        devices: [],
        devices_id: []
    },
    getters: { ...
    },
    mutations: { ...
    },
    actions: { ...
         async actionA(context) {
         },
         ...other actions...
    }
}
```

moduleB.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
namespaced: true,
    state: { 
        user_attr: null,
        user_tokens: null,
        signedIn: false
    },
    getters: { ...
    },
    mutations: { ...
    },
    actions: {
         actionB(context) {
              <some logic...>
              context.dispatch('moduleA/actionA', null, { root: true }); // THE LINE IN QUESTION
         },
         ...other actions...
    }
}
```

I am using vue-cli and dispatching actionB from Vue.app the following way in beforeCreate() hook: 
`this.$store.dispatch('moduleB/actionB');`

actionB is running fine until it hits the line in question above. 
the "undefined" tells me i am either doing something wrong in the dispatch of actionA or missed some other basic configuration of a moduled store.
to be clear, i kept some state objects, getters and mutations in the store.js main file as well, but moving these elsewhere does not solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that the exact error message you see? *'actionA undefined'*, nothing more?

Comment: @skirtle yes that is the exact message i see in the log.
for debug, I console.logged the store contents before dispatching actionB and i can clearly see the action is registered. so i am really lost as to why this is undefined. 
I was thinking it's related to the null i am passing as payload to the action, so i added payload argument to it and passing in an empty object - but that did not help in any way.

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard Vuex error message, at least not with a recent version of Vuex. There should be a link next to the entry in the console that you can click on to see where the logging is coming from. That may shed some light on what is going on. It looks suspiciously like console logging that you've added rather than a Vuex error.

Comment: @skirtle you're 100% right. I had some unmodified getter calls inside that action and indeed that is what returned the 'undefined' which caused this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you found the answer? I am also facing similar issue

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 see my latest reply. it was caused by some parts I neglected to refactor.